# Accessing objects using NSPredicate from Core Data

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, nspredicate

I tried to find answer to my simple question with no luck... I'm working on CoreData and i have two entities lets take an example of "Photo and Photographer" one to many relationship, means one photographer can have multiple photos... Now i did store objects using

```
[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName...]
```

I'm having issues retrieving "all photos" from a specific photographer. I'm using this code

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Photographer"];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@",@"photographerName"];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:YES]];
```

this code is returning photographer however i only need ALL photos taken by this photographer.
I'm new to CoreData, i'm not sure if i should be using "Photos" entity?

thanks in advance.

Comment: From this it appears like you are trying to sort your Photographer. First fetch the photographer then you can get the photos.

Answer (score 0):

Your fetch request should request `Photo` entity.

Then, in your predicate, you can specify the name of the photographer like so:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"photographer.name = %@",@"photographerName"];
```

Or better yet, it would be much faster to first get the photographer object, and then test the relationship in the predicate:

```
Photographer* photographer = ... //Get required photographer here
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"photographer = %@", photographer];
```

Comment: I'm interested in your approach. Would it be faster to fetch the photos using the method you used above or just get the `NSSet` of `Photo` objects from `photographer.photos` and sort that?

Comment: @cabellicar123 Using a maintained `photos` relationship would be fast too, because it already contains the list of the images, and a query is not performed.

Just remember, when you access a relationship, the items in that relationship are faulted, while items from a fetch request are not.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to sort the `photographer.photos` array.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortKey = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timestamp" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sorters = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortKey]; 
NSArray *sortedArray = [photographer.photos sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sorters];
```